# How do I find the exact URL of the index file that apt is downloading

Tags: apt

When I run `apt update`, apt reaches out to its repositories and downloads index files. How can I see the exact URL for every downloaded file?

Here's an example:

```bsh
apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
108 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Those `apt update` response lines **look** like URLs, but they're translated behind the scenes into something else. What is that "something else"? I'm looking for the full, precise URL of **every** file that apt is downloading with this command.

A little background: I'm trying to proxy the artifacts.elastic.co packages. I can't find the right path to use. The artifacts.elastic.co refuses to show the contents of directories, so I'm unable to use a web browser to look around for the correct magic path/URL.

Note: even though my example uses, `apt`, using `apt-get` or any other tool which shows me the full URL would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why not just ask `apt` or `apt-get` to show the URIs by adding the option `--print-uris`:

```
apt-get --print-uris update
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! While perusing man pages, I searched for "url". I guess I should have searched for "uri" - with an i!

Answer (score 5):

Doing it manually:

Start with `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease` in a web browser

[image]

The secret sauce is the `dists` directory. That's it. That's all you really need to know. Browse that directory, and you will find the InRelease file exactly where you expect.

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease

... becomes ...

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
```

Now, let's apply that knowledge to a different source:

```
https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable InRelease

... becomes ...

https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt/dists/stable/InRelease
```

When I open that URL in a web browser, the InRelease file downloads for me.

Comment: Good info, thanks! I accepted the other answer because it is closer to what I was looking for. However this is also useful for my future reference.

Answer (score -1):

Install `wireshark`. `https://www.wireshark.org/`.
Start `wireshark`, monitor your interface, do the `sudo apt update`. That will show you all the packets, including the Destination IP Address.

Comment: wireshark is available as a package, you don't need to futz with manual installation, but it doesn't show URLs for HTTPS, which this Q asked for

Answer (score -1):

Look at all the `open` calls. Read `man strace`, and do something like `sudo strace -e open apt update`.

Comment: URLs are not open'ed only sent as data over a socket, and for HTTPS encrypted

Comment: Yeah funnily enough I did try `strace`, and got exactly the behavior described by @dave_thompson_085. I couldn't spy on the software to find out what it was actually doing :sad_panda: